# Fomatting big numbers to string C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, numbers

If I need to update a stored value every second (or more often) and convert that value into a string to be displayed while also trying to make it more readable, what would be the most convenient/performant way to handle this? Aside from using a scientific notation.

Right now I'm using a float to store the value I want to show then I divide that number by a fixed amount (a thousand, a milion, a bilion ..) and assigning it a specific suffix (K, M, B ..); however I'm pretty sure this is not an elegant way of doing it.. Any advices?

The script is pretty much like this:

```
float x = 123456;
float y;

if (x >= 1000 && x < 1000000)
{ 
    y = (x / 1000);
    Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("0.000") + "K"); 
}

if (x >= 1000000 && x < 1000000000)
{
   y = (x / 1000000);
   Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("0.000") + "M"); 
}     

if (x >= 1000000000 && x < 1000000000000)
{ 
    y = (x / 1000000000);
    Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("0.000") + "B"); 
}
```

Which returns 123,456K

Comment: You should consider using the the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Too opinion-based.

Comment: First you should have `if-else if-else` statements and then I would expect that to output 123.456K.

Comment: Consider as an option MMOs-number format `1KKK` = `1 000 000 000` and electronics `1K5` = `1500` (Ohm ;).

Comment: @juharr - `ToString` uses `CurrentCulture` by default. Some cultures use `','` as decimal separator.

Comment: @juharr that's not the actual code, it's just a very quick example. At least try to answer to the topic.

Comment: @Corak Yes, but he OP had 123,456M before an edit.

Comment: @nk417 This is not where I would put an answer.  It's where I comment on your question, like how you had the result with an `M` instead of a `K` and a suggestion on how to structure the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
string[] suffixes = new string[]{ "", "K", "M", "B", "Q", "x10¹⁵", "x10¹⁸", "x10²¹", "x10²⁴" } ; // Replace with the suffixes you want
float number = 13248497894961536217986532f;
int suffixIndex = 0 ;
for( ; suffixIndex < suffixes.Length - 1 && number >= 1000 ; suffixIndex++ )
    number /= 1000;
Console.WriteLine( number.ToString("0.###") + suffixes[suffixIndex] ) ;
```

Note, if you don't provide enough suffixes, you may have an undesired result:

For instance `340282300000000x10²⁴` if you provide `float.MaxValue`

Comment: Tried out and that's great, thank you very much. I will probably use this as a base for what I need.